# If $a=\min(a_1,a_2)$, Can we show $a|z_1+z_2|\le|a_1z_1+a_2z_2|$?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

Let $a_i>0$, $a:=\min(a_1,a_2)$ and $z_i\in\mathbb C$. Does it hold $$a|z_1+z_2|\le|a_1z_1+a_2z_2|?\tag1$$ I mean, why clearly have $$a|z_1+z_2|\le a_1|z_1|+a_2|z_2|\tag2,$$ but that's not sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a_1=1, a_2=2, a=\min(a_1, a_2)=1, z_1=10, z_2=-1$$

$$|10-1|\le |10-2|$$

$$\text{False.}$$

Comment: You're absolutely right. I've encountered the claim in an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4692483/47771) to another question of me. Is there anything different?

Comment: sorry, I am not familar with that topic.

Answer (score 2):

No it does not hold. Take $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 2$, $z_1 = -2$ and $z_2 = 1$